# Rename the last 8 characters in filename

Tags: bash, rename, bash-script, patterns

I am receiving video files with different names but the final 8 characters of all are numbers (also different every time). This is the pattern of the file name:

```
custom text 00030402.avi
```

I have to make file name looks like this:

```
00\:03\:04\:02
```

So my question is how to rename the last 8 characters and preserve them to achieve this pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `rename` (the one from `perl` sometimes called `prename`, not from `util-linux`):

```
rename 's/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/$1:$2:$3:$4/'  *.avi
```

This would rename a filename like `custom text 00030402.avi` to `custom text 00:03:04:02.avi`.

If you backslashes in the filename (before the `:`), say:

```
rename 's/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/$1\\:$2\\:$3\\:$4/' *.avi
```

In order to remove the custom text from the filenames, say:

```
rename 's/.* (\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(.*)/$1\\:$2\\:$3\\:$4$5/' *.avi
```

Comment: Maybe something is wrong because I get the following error in terminal: Can't rename zlatin 00364220.avi zlatin 00:36:42:20.avi: Invalid argument

Comment: @ispasov What does `rename -n 's/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/$1:$2:$3:$4/' *.avi` say?

Comment: @ispasov And do you want backslashes (`\`) in the resulting filename?

Comment: `zlatin 00364220.avi renamed as zlatin 00:36:42:20.avi`

Comment: Yes I do want backslashes.

Comment: @ispasov If you want backslashes in the filename, you can say: `rename -n 's/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/$1\\:$2\\:$3\\:$4/' *.avi`

Comment: Here is the output: `zlatin 00364220.avi renamed as zlatin 00\:36\:42\:20.avi` Is it possible also to remove the custom text?

Comment: What do you mean by the custom text?  The `zlatin ` (including space) part?

Comment: That's right. `zlatin ` is custom text in this particular case.

Comment: @ispasov See edit above.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you. Just to be more specific the errors I got above were because my file was in a flash drive. When I moved it to the home directory, everything was fine.

Comment: Is `*.avi` necessary or I can left just `*` for any extension?

Comment: @ispasov You can say `*` as well.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
$ autoload zmv
$ zmv -v '(*)(??)(??)(??).avi' '$1\:$2\:$3\:$4.avi'
mv -- custom\ text\ 00030402.avi custom\ text\ 00\\:03\\:04\\:02.avi
```

(-v for verbose). To remove the *custom text*:

```
$ zmv -v '*(??)(??)(??)(??).avi' '$1\:$2\:$3\:$4.avi'
mv -- custom\ text\ 00030402.avi 00\\:03\\:04\\:02.avi
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with Perl regex lookahead:

```
perl -e '
    while($name=shift){
        @components = split /(?=(?:[0-9]{2})+[^0-9]+$)/,$name;
        shift @components;
        $new_name = join '\:',@components;
        rename $name => $new_name;
    }
' list_of_avi_files
```

This will work for any number of digit pairs, not just 4. You can also change `{2}` to `{3}`, for example, and have it split on digit triples.